# how to make Greek alphabet more readable

Tags: output-formatting

I often use $\alpha$,$\beta$ ,etc. in my mma program.

But when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> , They become `\[Alpha]` .which is longer.

So is there a **directly** way to copy they out to text?

Comment: See [`Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/9362)

Comment: I don't get this error in v. 11.3.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I mean ,when I copy it to , for example, txt, Vs Code.It will became `\[Alpha]`,`\[Beta]`, etc.

Comment: You need http://steampiano.net/msc/

Answer (score 1):

I have a indirectly way.

1. Turn the code into inputform.Like this.

[image]

2. Open Word, copy into it.

[image]

3. copy it from word.

get

```
α*β*γ
```